# Exibir conteúdo da tag <link rel=""> na página html?

Tags: html5

Estou tentando fazer um leitor de RSS, pesquisei e para isso usei:

```
<link rel="alternate"  type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="http://www.feedroll.com/rssviewer/feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gsmfans.org%2Findex.php%3Ftype%3Drss%3Baction%3D.xml&num=25&desc=1&au=y&date=y&tz=-3&targ=y&utf=y&pc=y">
```

Como faço para exibir o conteúdo que ele leu dessa página, na minha página? Ou seja, como mostrar o conteudo dessa página na minha página?

Comment: Você está falando de algo como um [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)?

Comment: pode ser também, quero um jeito de exibir o feed de noticias na pagina do site.. pois na realidade é um app, dai usei um script, mas quando compilo para wp ele não funciona.. Só que o iframe tem o src.. ele é que não esta aparecendo quando compilo

Comment: O que você quer é ler o feed rss do link?

Comment: sim, mas que não tenha o src, pois ao compilar o projeto no visual studio ele não funciona

Answer (score 1):

Como você está utilizando este feed2js para pegar o feed, e adicionar na página utilize o script dessa maneira:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.feedroll.com/rssviewer/feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gsmfans.org%2Findex.php%3Ftype%3Drss%3Baction%3D.xml&num=25&desc=1&au=y&date=y&tz=-3&targ=y&utf=y&pc=y"  charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Se quiser estilizar o conteúdo veja que o script gera uma estrutura com ul's e li's.

Comment: Eu coloquei dessa forma, funciona no navegador do computador, mas quando eu crio o mesmo projeto no VIsual Studio e compilo como app universal ele não funciona mais

Comment: @lvcs Como assim não funciona no VS? Poderia explicar em que quer que funcione? Por acaso não seria [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66743/tag-script-src-n%C3%A3o-funciona-quando-compilo-aplicativo-windows-phone-porque)?