# Tag script src não funciona quando compilo aplicativo (Windows Phone). Porque?

Tags: javascript, html5, windows-phone-8-1

Estou criando um app para um fórum, em algumas páginas eu quero exibir conteúdo de outros sites (esses online), para exibir imagem funciona de boa, mas para exibir um `rss` criado com uma ferramenta online ele não funciona, a linha é a seguinte:

```
< script src="http://www.feedroll.com/rssviewer/feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gsmfans.org%2Findex.php%3Ftype%3Drss%3Baction%3D.xml&num=25&desc=1&au=y&date=y&tz=-3&targ=y&utf=y&pc=y"  charset="UTF-8" >< /script>
```

Esse link leva a um arquivo `javascript` que vai escrevendo o `feed` de noticias na página, mas quando compilo ele não funciona, não sei se tem haver mas estou usando o `Jquery` comum para PC, o completo.. Tem outro meio de fazer o script rodar na minha página? Já tentei com iframe

Comment: Está assim (fora os espaços), ele é assim mesmo, no navegador do PC (opera) funciona de boa, mas quando eu compilo ou implanto o app no dispositivo e vou na página onde tem o código não aparece nada, o problema deve ser no Windows Phone, pois estou rodando um app em html5 e não um site..  Quando eu compilo e abro o arquivo gerando pelo WinRAR o código nos arquivos estão normais, sem alterações

Comment: É uma aplicação Cordova?

Comment: No inicio era, quando compilo pelo Cordova/Phonegap ele funciona, porém o app não fica muito agradável, perde muita qualidade no desing etc. É um projeto do Visual Studio mesmo, no Visual tem a opção de apps html5